# Strange casting behaviour. Cannot cast object (int) to long

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I have the following code:

```
int intNumber1 = 100;
object intNumber2 = 100;
bool areNumberOfTheSameType = intNumber1.GetType() == intNumber2.GetType(); // TRUE
bool areEqual = intNumber1.Equals(intNumber2); // TRUE

long longNumber1 = (long) intNumber1; // OK
long longNumber2 = (long) intNumber2; // InvalidCastException. Why?
```

Why doesn't the second cast work? I realize that it might be because the object doesn’t have an explicit cast to a long, but if we look at its type on runtime it is `System.Int32`.

If I use `var` or `dynamic` instead of `object`, it works.

Any thoughts?

Comment: try changing that to  
`long longNumber2 = (long)(int)intNumber2;`

Comment: Why would you want to use an object instead of a var in this instance? Its better to keep variables strongly typed where possible

Comment: @Quinn351: my guess is that the above code illustrates a simplified issue the user has, I don't think we should take it as a current practice.

Comment: @liho1eye. Thank you. It works, Moreover your suggestion pointed me to right direction in fidning the answet. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Cast from `int` to `long` is interpreted as conversion between the two types.

Cast from `object` to `int` is interpreted as unboxing a boxed `int`.

It is the same syntax, but it says two different things.

In the working cases (`int`→`long`, `object` (boxed `int`)→`int`), the compiler knows exactly what code to produce. If boxed `int`→`long` was to work, the compiler would have to somehow figure out which conversion to use, but it doesn't have enough information to do it.

See also [this blog post from Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/).

Comment: @Bashir Magomedov: Eric Lippert's blog post on this is quite good, would highly recommend you read it.

Comment: @R0MANARMY Thank you guys! I've read it. It's very comprehensive. 
@svick. Thank you. It's clear now.

Answer (score 16):

The `object` holds a type `int`. But it's considered an object (which is a boxed int) and a boxed value type can generally only be cast to its underlying type (the type that is boxed).

*To cast it to another type, you first have to cast it to its underlying type.* This works:

```
long longNumber2 = (long) (int) intNumber2;
```

The reason that `var` works is that the compiler infers the type at compile time. That means, when you use `var`, the type of `intNumber2` (if you use `typeof`) will be `int`. Whereas when you use `object`, the type will be `object`.

Using `dynamic` is a whole different process and cannot be compared with `var`. Here, the conversion / casting takes place at runtime, using reflection and the DLR library. It will dynamically find the underlying type, find that it has a conversion operator and uses that.

Answer (score 4):

That it doesn't work due to being two different types of casts (one converting, the other unboxing) has already been stated in answers here. What might be a useful addition, is that `Convert.ToInt64()` will convert anything that is either a built-in type that can be converted to long, or a type of a class that implements `IConvertible.ToInt64()`, into a long. In other words, if you want to be able to cast an object that contains an integer (of whatever size) to long, `Convert.ToInt64()` is the way to go. It is more expensive, but what you are trying to do **is** more expensive that casting, and the difference is negliable (just big enough to be wasteful in cases where you know the object must be a boxed long).

Answer (score 3):

(Caution: Guess)

`Int32` has a conversion operator to `Int64` which is what gets invoked when you do the first cast. `Object` doesn't, so your second cast is trying to cast an object to another type which isn't a supertype (`Int64` doesn't inherit `Int32`).

The reason why it works with `var` is obvious – the compiler just saves you from typing `int` in that case. With `dynamic` the runtime does all necessary checks for what needs to be done while normally the compiler would just insert either the cast or invoke the conversion operator.

Answer (score -1):

You need to unbox to the same type that was boxed.

```
object intNumber2 = 100L;
// or value in the long type range
// object intNumber2 = 9223372036854775806;

long result = (long)intNumber2;
```

Comment: You can also add the `L` to the number, no need for a large number.