# Pass an object variable to method - Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, object, types, casting

I have a list of objects (their types are unknown ahead of time). The example below shows hard coded values, but my actual code populates the args list by reading from a CSV file. I then want to pass this list of args to a typical method that asks for certain parameters. So I cast the elements to the required types as shown. I'm getting error:

> Specified cast is not valid

when the method is called at run time. How should I go about accomplishing this?

```
var args = new List<object>();
        args.Add(5495);
        args.Add("String1");
        args.Add(10133);
        args.Add("String2");

        result = request.GetCustomer((long) args[0], (string) args[1], (int) args[2], (string) args[3]);
```

Comment: The error is specifically telling you why you can't perform the cast, including what the actual type of the object is and what you're trying to cast it to.  You'll need to cast the object to its *actual* type, if you want it to not fail at runtime.

Comment: Well, a good start would be a try catch block around this and a count so that you can see which row in your csv is the culprit.

Comment: @Kell A `try`/`catch` block would just obscure the problem.  He can already see the error, he merely needs to fix the bug in his code.

Comment: you'll want to safe cast these values, so `args[0] as long`

Comment: @Servy The bug might be in the data passed to the code from the csv file.

Comment: @CallumLinington That would in no way fix the problem, it would just result in the code not working but without throwing.

Comment: @Kell If so, then he'd need to fix that bug.  Either way, he knows exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @CallumLinington `args[0] as long` won't even compile.

Comment: You can find some additional information why your case fails in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541680/strange-casting-behaviour-cannot-cast-object-int-to-long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add value types to `List<object>()`,

```
args.Add(5495);
```

the item will be [***Boxed***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx). The above line causes `5495` to be boxed from `int`. To ***unbox***, you need to explicitly cast `args[0]` to its type as - `(int)args[0]`. So, if your method is accepting `long` as its first parameter, do `(long)(int)args[0]`. You unboxed `args[0]` and then cast the value to `long`.

Comment: Thank you!!! This fixed the problem, and I actually realized that I could just cast that parameter as (int) rather than (long).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 5495 will have a type of int and you are trying to cast it to a long. You can get round this in several ways, here is one of them;

Replace this;

```
(long) args[0]
```

with this;

```
(long) (int) args[0]
```

This wouldn't be a very useful solution however since you could never actually pass your method a long value, instead you can do this;

```
args.Add((long) 5495);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using Convert.ChangeType

```
      var args = new List<object>();
        args.Add(5495);
        args.Add("String1");
        args.Add(10133);
        args.Add("String2");


        long aLong = (long)Convert.ChangeType(args[0], typeof(long), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        string aStr = (string)Convert.ChangeType(args[1], typeof(string), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        int aInt = (int)Convert.ChangeType(args[2], typeof(int), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

create separate class for store list data

*class Test{*

private long Variable1{get;set;}

private string Variable2{get;set;}

private long Variable3{get;set;}

private string Variable4{get;set;}

}

var args=new List();

var obj=new Test{

Variable1=5495,

Variable2="String1",

Variable3=10133,

Variable4="String2"

}

args.add(obj);

result=request.GetCustomer(args[0].Variable1,args[0].Variable2,args[0].Variable3,args[0].Variable4);

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the problem a bit.

```
var args = new List<object>();
args.Add(5495);
var l = (long)args[0]; // throws an exception
```

What exactly is inside args[0]? An `int` (because `5495` is an int to the compiler, if you want it to be a long, type `5495L`). More precisely, a *boxed* `int`, because you had to store it in a reference-type storage location. A boxed struct can only be unboxed to the same struct or to a nullable of this struct. In our case

```
var i = (int)args[0];
var nullable = (Nullable<int>)args[0];
var nullable1 == (int?)args[0];
```

would all work fine.

You can cast the value to anything it's compatible with after you've unboxed it though.

You can read more about boxing and unboxing on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx). It's a very precious understanding if you want to use C# efficiently.

The root cause of your problem is you're using a `List<object>` though, making the boxing unavoidable. It's pretty rare you really need to do that, you should probably think your architecture over to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the recommended reading on boxing/unboxing (especially on the performance). I am such a noob. Yes this design is probably not ideal. I was having to call different methods with 20-30 parameters for each of them, so I was tired of defining 20-30 variables for each method --> list of objects. I'm all ears if you have a better recommendation for my situation. Thanks!

Comment: 20-30 parameters is *a lot*. Any sane method should probably not have that much. You should probably refactor most of those in some custom classes that makes sense in your business logic, and pass a couple of these objects to your method.

Comment: These are mostly web service methods that create certain types of data (e.g. a company's record with lots of data about the company). Yes as I go along I'll probably refactor some common fields.