# Direct convert returns InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, sql, generics, xamarin

I have a method with generics return type that works with my `SQLite` database:

```cs
    public static T SelectScalar<T>(string sql)
    {
        // some code...
        var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
        return (T)result;
    }
```

While calling it like this: `SqliteReader.SelectScalar<int>(mysql);` the `InvalidCastException` raised on return line. What's wrong with it? I'm quite new with generics, please tell, what's wrong? TIA.

**EDIT**
Screenshot with `result` content:
[image: result content]

Comment: What **is** `result` when executing the line? I assume it´s something like `"3"` or `3.3` even `DBNull`. Anyway why do you wrapp the `ExecuteScalar` into your own method at all?

Comment: @HimBromBeere it's of `object` type.

Comment: the exception message should tell you what 2 types cannot be casted. please tell us

Comment: I ment what is its **value**, not its **type**.

Comment: @HimBromBeere ok, it's 70

Comment: so does the exception message tell you : "cannot cast INT to INT" ? or does it tell you "cannot cast INT to INT? " ? and you shou call your method: `SqliteReader.SelectScalar<int?>(mysql);`

Comment: if it really **were** `70`, you won´t get that exception. Move your mouse over `result` when debugging and write the **exact** value. I bet you have either a comma or some double-quotes here.

Comment: please post the message of the exception and preferably a screenshot from the debugger showing the contents of `result`. This would make it very much easier to help you

Comment: " it's of object type." apparently not. The debugger shows `long`

Comment: @MongZhu @HimBromBeere ok, I've pasted a screenshot.. really strange, that result's type is `long`..

Comment: but that should not be a problem. since it is an explicit cast this should work actually

Comment: how about this **exception message** ???

Comment: @MongZhu it's a Xamarin app, there is a poor exception message, just `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

Comment: please try this: change `var result` to `object result` and try again

Comment: @MongZhu no, still the same.. Added try/catch, no inner Exception, no additional information, only `specified cast is not valid`)

Comment: ok last attempt, I think it has something to do with the [sql DB return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) I guess you cannot cast it. please try `return Convert.ToInt(result);`

Comment: @MongZhu That of course works, but wouldn't been working with other types. I know, I can call method like: `SelectScalar<object>(...)` and cast it over the method, but just wanted to do all the staff inside it.

Comment: ok last attempt: try this: `return (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, T);` I am out of options now ;)

Comment: ok then I write an answer

Comment: Whenever you mention exception in the question, please add exact message and stacktrace - this will provide useful information and will not lead to useless discussions and a tons of questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange casting behaviour. Cannot cast object (int) to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541680/strange-casting-behaviour-cannot-cast-object-int-to-long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently the type [BigInt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) cannot simply be casted to an `int`. According to this [post](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/279390-specified-cast-not-valid-error-executescalar) it seems to be a

> IIRC you are getting a SqInt32 struct which is castable to Int32

In your case probably a `SqInt64` struct. You need to convert it

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));
```

I also would suggest to restrict the generic parameter at least down to structs:

```
public static T SelectScalar<T>(string sql) where T: struct
```

Comment: The actual problem is because of unboxing, which cannot do both unboxing and cast/conversion at the same time. Unboxing will only attempt to unbox the exact type you ask it to, so `(int)objectValue` expects an `int` in that boxed object, nothing else. Whether the actual boxed value can be converted to an int or not is not taken into consideration at all.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen yes I read the duplicate suggestion yesterday. I will change the answer and include the part with the boxing when I find the time. Or you use your gold hammer and close this question as duplicate

Comment: @ДенисЧорный actually the answer by Benjamin Podszun is the correct one. You should accept it. so I can delete mine and we can close this post as a duplicate

Comment: I'm partial to the Convert.ChangeType approach though, or Convert.ToInt32, but if it is known to always be a boxed long, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteScalar()` returns an `object`, in this case a boxed `long`.

If you cast an object to an `int`, it tries to unbox .. an actual `int`. Casting a `long` to an `int` would be a conversion instead.

A cast that would work for these specific lines (but .. wouldn't help you) is

```
return (T)(long)result;
```

Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541712/59492